# Magento2 unit tests doesn't run using vendor/bin/phpunit or vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

Tags: unit-tests, phpunit, magento2.2.2

Env:

PHP 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+Clear Magento 2.2.2 with sample data (downloaded in archive)

I have created new test module that very simple with unit test for one class.
When I run

```
php bin/magento dev:tests:run unit
```

Everything ok, tests are running (including mine)
But when I try to run only my tests using :

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Test/Unit
```

it returns the following message:

> You need to set up the project dependencies using Composer:
>
> `composer install`
>
> You can learn all about Composer on https://getcomposer.org/.

I run `composer install`:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>
> Nothing to install or update
>
> Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
>
> Generating autoload files

If I try to run:

```
php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --filter MyTestingClassTest
```

It returns:

> PHPUnit 6.2.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
>         phpunit [options]
>
> Code Coverage Options:
>
> --coverage-clover     Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format.
>
> --coverage-crap4j     Generate code coverage report in Crap4J XML format.
>
> ...
>
> Logging Options:
>
> --log-junit           Log test execution in JUnit XML format to file.
>
> ...
>
> Test Selection Options:
>
> --filter           Filter which tests to run.
>
> --testsuite       Filter which testsuite to run.
>
> --group ...                 Only runs tests from the specified group(s).
>
> ...

And so on.

So does anybody faced with this issue?

I'm not new Magento2 but new in unit testing so I can miss something primary. 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
PHPUNIT doesn't installed globally, I tried all steps above on another magento instalation v2.2.1 and I have the same issue.

Comment: Try to change into the directory dev/tests/unit and run phpunit from there, I think the bootstrap relies on some relative paths

Comment: Sir will you please let me know that how to run MFTF?? I tried vendor\bin\mftf but it return `vendor is not recognized` the Unit Testing is working fine for me but in case of `xml` file I cannot run this

Answer (score 7):

**./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Test/Unit**

Try Below Command instead of yours

**./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Test/Unit**

---

You need to set up the project dependencies using Composer:

composer install

You can learn all about Composer on https://getcomposer.org/.

---

This error occur because phpunit is not symlink with actual path so first you need to create symlink using below command

**ln -s ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit  ./vendor/bin/phpunit**

or if you are facing issue in symlink so you can run unit test by below command as well.

**./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Block**

Comment: Worked for me using 
**./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Block**

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem (though not with Magento). Try reinstalling phpunit.

- Remove phpunit from composer.json
- $ composer update
- Add phpunit back to composer.json
- $ composer update

Source: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1613#issuecomment-74474966

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem (though not with Magento). Try reinstalling phpunit.

1. Remove composer.json
2. Remove composer.lock

Add these files and then start below command: 
http://www.mediafire.com/file/sk8x02qpl42z3pd/composer.json/file

$ composer update